# EDX CS50x PSET3 recover.c (recovered image does not match: applies to the 049.jpg file only)

Tags: c, jpeg, cs50, image-size, recover

I'm stuck in this problem:

Result:
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:) recovers 000.jpg correctly
:) recovers middle images correctly
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match

The file compiles correctly and all the 50 .jpg files are clear, however there is this small issue with the last file (049.jpg: recovered image does not match) and I just cannot figure out the reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure 1 command-line argument:
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: name of forensic image from which to recover JPEGs");
        return 1;
    }
    // open the memory card file:
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        fclose(file);
        return 2;
    }
    //fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    char* filename = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
    if (!filename)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    bool jpeg_found = false;
    int f = 0;
    int n = 0;

    while (!(feof(file)))
    {
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", f);
        FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (!filename) return 6;
        if (f > 0) fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
        n = 0;

        while (n == 0)
        {
            if (feof(file))
            {
                fclose(img);
                break;
            }
            fread(buffer, 1, 512, file);    //read 512 bytes into a buffer
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&        // start of a new JPEG?
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff && (
            buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                if (jpeg_found) // have you already found a JPEG or not?
                {
                    // YES: close the previous file and open a new one,
                    fclose(img);
                    f += 1;
                    n = 1;
                }
                else // NO: start very 1st JPEG
                {
                    fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
                    jpeg_found = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (jpeg_found) // Have your already found a JPEG or not?
                {
                    // YES: Those 512 bytes belong to the current opened JPEG file
                    fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
                }
                else  // NO: Discard the 512 bytes and go to the start of the loop
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(filename);
    fclose(file);
```

Comment: ”while (!(feof(file)))" is a bug, it doesnt work.

Comment: thanks, amended it, did not solve the issue though. Didn't know that, but checked here and indeed while (!(feof(file))) is not correct!

Comment: You're opening a binary file in text mode. Should be `"rb"`. Same for writing

Comment: Also, what does a file name have to do with `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: I was using sizeof(char) and changed to sizeof(int) to malloc space for 50(files) x 4 bytes (instead of 1 byte) and then changed to malloc(400) as sizeof(int) = 4 bytes is not enough to store the filename (xxx.jpg). But it turned out no changes to the program. Thanks, changed to 'rb' and 'wb', but the issue remains the same.